# Pairing two algebra structures of the same type and result the same type of algebra structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found one can pair two algebra structure and result the same type of algebraic structure.

For example, if $(S,+)$ and $(T,+')$ are semigroup. Let $M=S\times T$ and $(a,b)\oplus(c,d)$ is defined as $(a+c,b+'d)$. Then $(M,\oplus)$ is a semigroup.

Of course this also holds for monoids, groups.

What other algebra structure has this property? Are there any underlying principle behind it?

Answer (score 2):

See "Product Algebra" from [Universal Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra#Basic_constructions).

Answer (score 0):

Any variety of "universal algebra" has this property.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. You have found on your own the concept of a [direct product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product).

The result you have found is true as well and falls under the first part of Birkhoff's theorem.

The first part of the result roughly states that if you have two structures that satisfy some set of equations and you take their direct product then you will have another structure of that kind.

Now here's some research for you: If we know the substructures of two given structures then can we say something about the substructures of their direct product?